# Post message on the same line

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have my bot print the word with all of the guessed letters and unknown letters. I want the entire statement to be printed on one line, but because of how I am using `for char in word` (so it checks if each word is correctly guessed or not), it prints every character on a different line.

```
for char in word:      
    if char in guesses:   
        await bot.say(char)
    else:
        await bot.say("_")     
        failed = failed + 1
```

How would I go about fixing this as I know that you can use `sys.stdout.flush()` with regularly printing, but I can't find a way to get that attribute working in my program as of yet.

EDIT:
I got it to work by using this code where I add the character or _ to a string variable and then say it all at once. Credit to abccd for this idea!

```
text = ""
for char in word:      
    if char in guesses:    
        text = text + char
    else:
        text = (text + " - ")
        failed = failed + 1
await bot.say(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to send a continuous string since `.say()` sends a new message every time it's called. So you'll need to join the word before you call `.say()`.

```
text = "".join(c if c in guesses or c.isspace() else "_" for c in word)
failed = text.count("_")

await bot.say(text)
```

(p.s. I think in hangman, you also show the spaces.)

Comment: that's why I have the bot.say("_"). that indicates a blank space

Comment: I don't see your point, "_" also represents an unguessed letter, so it's impossible to tell a space from a unknown letter in your code.

Comment: OOOHHH! I didn't get your questions, none of my words have spaces in them. (I use a RNG to choose from a list of about 50 words) This way I will never need to account for spaces in a word.

Comment: The answer still solves the problem, just remove the `or c.isspace()` part. Though it wouldn't hurt to leave it in there, just in case you want your game to support spaces later on. :)

Comment: To new users joining the SO community, welcome! After you accumulate answer(s) to your question, you can choose one answer that solves your problem the best. For that answer, you may click the check mark ✅ under the votes to mark your question as solved, this will indicate to others that your question had been solved. Note that accepting is completely your choice.